# Unable to resolve host FQDN in fedora 32 linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, fedora

I am connecting through wifi and when I am connecting to the VPN thereafter my /etc/resolv.conf is getting updated as below.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver IPV6_address
nameserver IPv4_address
nameserver IPv4_address
```

After VPN connection, I am unable to resolve some of the FQDN but able to resolve them with their IP address.

```
Error -
FQDN: Name or service not known
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `FQDN' on position 1 (argc 1)
```

To resolve it temporarily, I am updating the /etc/resolve.conf to make IP4 DNS servers as first and IPv6 DNS servers as last as shown below.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
#nameserver IPV6_address
nameserver IPv4_address
nameserver IPv4_address
nameserver IPV6_address
```

After this change and without any restart the FQDN and IP address resolution works fine.

But I am trying to understand why if the first IPv6 DNS is not able to resolve my FQDN its not sending the DNS resolve request to the other DNS IPv4 DNS resolvers below. This is happening specifically on my Linux machine.

On my Windows machine it works without any modifications.

Kindly help me get some understanding on this.

Comment: Contact your VPN provider to ensure that they have not broken IPv6 connectivity. Broken or unimplemented IPv6 on your VPN would cause this problem.

Comment: But it works on windows machine without any issues and also I could see the same set of DNS servers list present in ipconfig /all output with ipv6 dns address being the first.

Comment: You aren't using Windows.

Comment: On Windows, are the same DNS server used?

Comment: Yes, ipv6 dns is provided by the isp vendor and other two ip4 dns are added by vpn connection